# MongoDB How to convert IEnumerable to Bson.BsonValue using C#?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a model that looks like this that I want to save to a MongoDB collection

```
public string Property1 {get; set; } 
public string Property2 {get; set; }
public IEnumerable<CustomClass> Property3 { get; set;}
```

When trying to save to MongoDB, I can do the following:

```
var temp = new BsonDocument();
temp["Property1"] = model.Property1;
temp["Property2"] = model.Property2;

collection.InsertOne(temp);
```

How do I add Property3? I get a compile time error If try and do:

```
temp["Property3"] = model.Property3 //Cannot convert IEnumerble<CustomClass> to MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue
```

What is the trick to converting my IEnumerble< CustomClass > to a MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue? CustomClass just has two string properties in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can foreach over your IEnumerable and create BsonDocument each containing the two string properties.

```
var doc = new BsonDocument
{
  { "property1", obj.Property1 },
  { "property2", obj.Property2 }
};
```

add the BsonDocument's to a BsonArray-

```
BsonArray array = new BsonArray();
...
array.Add(doc);
...
```

Then later when you need to do some save operation like a Update, you can use the SetWrapped method of the UpdateBuilder--

```
Update.Set(...)
      .SetWrapped("customClasses", array)
...
```

I haven't used mongodb for a bit so just looking at some code I previously wrote.